# Computers inside computers?

Tags: if-statement, boolean-logic

I was creating some simple python if-statements to act as logic gates and i had a cool idea: the processors of computers are simply many logic gates strung together.

So would it be possible to create a program with many complex if-statements to act like the logic gates in the processor to "create" a computer in the computer?

Comment: Yes, it's possible and has been done many times already.

Comment: @user1095108 how can i do it?

Comment: Is it possible to create a program with many `if` statements?  Yes, yes it is.  Why would you think it wouldn't be?  You can write as much code as you want in your program.

Comment: Google for virtualbox and dosbox and look into their source code.

Comment: @user1095108 so what I've described would be like creating my own virtualbox like software?

Comment: Yes, or many other progams like it.

Comment: @sir_ian No, VirtualBox uses your CPU directly, executing the OS's code directly on your CPU. With your code, it will execute the OS on your program, which then executes on the host CPU, thus being significantly slower and less capable.